# How do I count events with multiple boolean variables in Keen IO?

Tags: analytics, keen-io, bigdata

Say one of my Keen IO event properties is an object of booleans: { "is_a": true, "is_b": true, "is_c": false, ... }.

How would I get a count of how many events have each boolean set to true?

i.e. I'd like to get a result that tells me that in the last week there were:

- 100 events with is_a true
- 60 events where is_b was true
- 70 events where is_c was true

Is there any way to do this without making a separate call for each of is_a/b/c?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to simply run 3 counts for this query, each with a single filter.

However, there is a way you could do it in a single query.

Run a count and `group_by` by all three properties.

```
var count = new Keen.Query("count", {
  event_collection: "purchases",
  group_by: ["is_a", "is_b", "is_c"]
});
```

This will count all of the true and false values for all of the combinations of these properties, and you'd have to parse them to pick out the individual cases.

It's less complicated to run the count 3 times.